# Why does a photon have linear momentum, although it doesn't possess mass?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

We know that photon doesn't possess mass. But it has a tendency of colliding with surfaces, as we see in the photoelectric effect. As it doesn't possess mass, then how does it have linear momentum?

$E=mc^2$ and $E=hc/\lambda$

$mc = h/\lambda =p$

Here $m=0 \Rightarrow p=0$.
But photons can collide.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation

Comment: Photon **does** have mass. It doesn't have _rest mass_, but that's another story.

Comment: Moving mass= rest mass/√1-(v/c)^2 now as rest mass =0 then moving mass must be zero

Comment: @jay it does not work like that for light.  The formula you give is undefined when $v=c $.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is really a physics question, with answers over on physics SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, Physics is good at answering "what" and "how" questions, it doesn't do very well at answering "why" questions except reductively or tautologically. There's several ways to answer your question, but they really don't satisfy (imho) anyone who seriously wants to know why photons have momentum - at least not in any fundamental sense. I think the better question is:"What led you to believe that having mass is a prerequisite for having momentum?" Chances are, you were told something that you interpreted to mean that. No. Photons have momentum because that is the way our Universe works. Or another way to answer is: Anything that has energy has momentum. The energy of anything can be divided into potential and kinetic energy. There is a intimate relationship between momentum and energy - for example what is the derivative of ½mv² with respect to velocity? (and what is the integral of mv dv?) It turns out that momentum and energy are two aspects of the same Laws of Physics. I'm not sure if these various answers can help or not. It may be possible to imagine a Universe in which only things with *rest mass* also carried momentum. If so, I am unaware of how you could go about such imagining.

Answer (score 2):

The formula for the momentum, $p = mv$ is only valid in the context of [classical mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum). For photons, energy and momentum are related by $E = pc$, which, because $E = hv = \frac{hc}{\lambda}$ leads to the following formula: $p = \frac{h}{\lambda}$. So the momentum is always non-zero and depends only on the wavelength.

See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon#Physical_properties) for more details.

Comment: But mass of photon is zero how can it collide?

Comment: Mass isn't important; momentum is.

Comment: But this are contradicting!

Comment: No, it's not. Just like you can't use $E=mc^2$ to determine the energy of a photon, you can't use $p=mc$ to determine the momentum.

Comment: Means planks theory and Einstein's theory can not be co-relate?

Comment: Not in this simple way. It's something physicists have been researching for decades now.

Comment: Our teacher told us the experiment of plank was explained by Einstein theory of relatively. Its difficult to relate particle and wave nature of light!

Comment: Actually momentum _is_ mass times velocity.  But the mass includes the equivalent mass due to the energy of motion.  What doesn't work from Newtonian mechanics is the assumption that mass is independent of motion.  Thus a photon moving with energy $E$ and speed $c$ has mass  $E/{c^2}$ and momentum $(E/{c^2})(c)=E/c$.